# How do I get the difference between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the date difference between 2 dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-date-difference-between-2-dates-using-php)

```
date1=2010-11-10 09:49:54;
date2=2010-11-10 09:49:54;
```

How do I get difference between these two dates in PHP?

Comment: try to search first before posting the question

Answer (score 2):

```
$difference = strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2);
```

The difference will be in seconds.

Comment: both `$date1 , $date2` is the same unless is a typo